# Relative costs of DELETE / INSERT call pair vs an 'if exists' check beforehand?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We're trying to figure out what the relative costs are between a couple of approaches.

We have a web page where people choose to add/keep/remove rows from a table, by marking them with checkboxes.  (People can add new entries to the page as well as see existing ones.)

When posted to the web server the page loops over the entries and calls a stored procedure, passing in the state of the checkbox as one of the parameters.

The stored procedure currently calls a `delete` statement for each entry, followed by an `insert` if the checkbox is marked.  This has the virtue of simplicity.

We're thinking instead of putting some `if exists` logic in there, to test whether the row is already in the table.

If so and the checkbox is marked, we'd leave it alone.  Otherwise we'd insert it.  Conversely, if the row isn't in the table and the checkbox is unmarked, we'd skip the `delete` and `insert` statements.  This minimizes the number of `deletes` and such but at a cost of more logic.

In terms of load on the database, is one approach generally preferred to the other?

Is there a cost to calling `delete` statements that don't, in fact, affect any rows, as would be the case when adding new records?  Is this worse than an `if exists` check?

The table is indexed on all relevant columns.  I assume for posting 600,000 entries there would be a big advantage to checking beforehand, but the page in question will have 100 entries at most.

Comment: Why not use a Merge statement? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan [MERGE has a number of unresolved bugs](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug), and on top of that [it doesn't buy you any more atomicity or concurrency control than you can get otherwise](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx), so I've stopped recommending it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem you're going to have with performance here is that you are calling a stored procedure for every entry - it really doesn't matter if inside that stored procedure you use `DELETE/INSERT` or check first, you're still going to have the overhead of 600K procedure calls, some potentially large portion of 600K logged transactions, etc.

I strongly recommend you look at [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Your C# or whatever can pass a *set* of 600K entries to a *single* stored procedure, once, and then you can perform two set-based operations (pseudo-code):

```
 UPDATE src SET val = t.val
   FROM dbo.tvp INNER JOIN dbo.source AS src
   ON t.key = src.key;

 INSERT src SELECT x FROM dbo.tvp AS t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM src WHERE key = t.key);
```